# Is there a way to update the host in flask behind gunicorn in kubernetes

Tags: nginx, flask, kubernetes, gunicorn, kubernetes-ingress

While working on an API written with flask and flask restplus, I have had an issue. Indeed, I need to do an action which is asynchronous, so I return a `http` response with a status code `202` and a Location header: `/api/tasks/{id}`. Flask takes this path and add the host in front of it, so we receive something like this: `http://host/api/tasks/{id}`. The issue is that the host is always in `http`, even if the api is in a kubernetes cluster with nginx ingress, and launched with gunicorn, and `https` is activated within the k8s cluster. Does someone has an idea of how I can return the location, but with `https`?

I have tried https://marcolenzo.eu/2019/12/01/enable-x-forwarded-headers-in-kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller/

Thanks for your help.